# How to dynamically show/hide sub properties of personally defined Property using qt property

Tags: c++, qt, qproperty

info:
We are trying to create a property whose sub properties may be added/removed depending on the value of another sub property.

An example of this could be an plant object.  This object has one property which will be a drop down consisting of types of plants, lets say (daisy, daffodil, and venus fly trap).  If venus is selected, I would like to have a property show up below called avgFlyIntake but if daffodil is selected this property should disappear.

```
example:
Plant
  type       venus
  avgFlyI    2.0
  avgHight   3.0

 Or

Plant
  type       daffodil
  avgHight   8.0
  //Fly Property gone or grayed out.
```

**Edit:** Essentially plant is a property of another model that I guess could be called livingThing.  The property's show up in a hierarchical fashion in a 2 column table.  I'd like the plant properties to be dynamically hidden if it is possible.

```
c++ src:
PlantProperty::PlantProperty(const QString& name /*= QString()*/, QObject* propertyObject /*= 0*/, QObject* parent /*= 0*/)
    : Property(name, propertyObject, parent)
{

    m_type = new Property("id", this, this);
    m_avgFlyIntake = new Property("avgFlyIntake", this, this);
    m_avgHeight = new Property("avgHeight", this, this);

    //setEditorHints("...");
}
enum PlantProperty::getType() const{
    return value().value<Plant>().getType();
}

void PlantProperty::setType(enum enabled){
    //if enum changed show and hide relevant properties associated with selection
    Property::setValue(QVariant::fromValue(Plant(...)));
}
```

```
c++ h:
class PlantProperty : public Property{
    Q_OBJECT
/**/
    Q_PROPERTY(int type READ getType WRITE setType DESIGNABLE true USER true)
    Q_PROPERTY(float avgFlyIntake READ getavgFlyIntake WRITE setAvgFlyIntake DESIGNABLE true USER ture)
    Q_PROPERTY(float avgHeight READ getavgHeight WRITE setavgHeihgt DESIGNABLE true USER true)

public:
    PlantProperty (const QString&name = QString(), QObject* propertyObject = 0, QObject* parent = 0);

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    QVariant value(int role = Qt::UserRole) const;
    virtual void setValue(const QVariant& value);

    void setEditorHints(const QString& hints);

    int getType() const;
    void setType(int id);

private:
    QString parseHints(const QString& hints, const QChar component);

    Property* type;
    Property* avgFlyIntake;
    Property* avgHeight;

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Plant)
#endif //PLANTPROPERTY_H
```

```
q property model:
// *************************************************************************************************
//
// QPropertyEditor v 0.3
//   
// --------------------------------------
// Copyright (C) 2007 Volker Wiendl
// Acknowledgements to Roman alias banal from qt-apps.org for the Enum enhancement
//
//
// The QPropertyEditor Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation version 3 of the License 
//
// The Horde3D Scene Editor is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
//
// *************************************************************************************************

#include "QPropertyModel.h"

#include "Property.h"
#include "EnumProperty.h"

#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QMetaProperty>
#include <QtGui/QItemEditorFactory>

struct PropertyPair
{
    PropertyPair(const QMetaObject* obj, QMetaProperty property) : Property(property), Object(obj) {}

    QMetaProperty      Property;
    const QMetaObject* Object;

    bool operator==(const PropertyPair& other) const {return QString(other.Property.name()) == QString(Property.name());}
};


QPropertyModel::QPropertyModel(QObject* parent /*= 0*/) : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{   
    m_rootItem = new Property("Root",0, this);   
}


QPropertyModel::~QPropertyModel()
{
}

QModelIndex QPropertyModel::index ( int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent /*= QModelIndex()*/ ) const
{
    Property *parentItem = m_rootItem;
    if (parent.isValid())
        parentItem = static_cast<Property*>(parent.internalPointer());  
    if (row >= parentItem->children().size() || row < 0)
        return QModelIndex();       
    return createIndex(row, column, parentItem->children().at(row));    

}

QModelIndex QPropertyModel::parent ( const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();

    Property *childItem = static_cast<Property*>(index.internalPointer());
    Property *parentItem = qobject_cast<Property*>(childItem->parent());

    if (!parentItem || parentItem == m_rootItem)
        return QModelIndex();

    return createIndex(parentItem->row(), 0, parentItem);
}

int QPropertyModel::rowCount ( const QModelIndex & parent /*= QModelIndex()*/ ) const
{
    Property *parentItem = m_rootItem;
    if (parent.isValid())
        parentItem = static_cast<Property*>(parent.internalPointer());  
    return parentItem->children().size();
}

int QPropertyModel::columnCount ( const QModelIndex & /*parent = QModelIndex()*/ ) const
{
    return 2;
}

QVariant QPropertyModel::data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role /*= Qt::DisplayRole*/ ) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    Property *item = static_cast<Property*>(index.internalPointer());
    switch(role)
    {
    case Qt::ToolTipRole:       
    case Qt::DecorationRole:
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
    case Qt::EditRole:
        if (index.column() == 0)
            return item->objectName().replace('_', ' ');
        if (index.column() == 1)
            return item->value(role);
    case Qt::BackgroundRole:
        if (item->isRoot()) return QApplication::palette("QTreeView").brush(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Button).color();
        break;
    };
    return QVariant();
}

// edit methods
bool QPropertyModel::setData ( const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role /*= Qt::EditRole*/ )
{
    if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole)
    {
        Property *item = static_cast<Property*>(index.internalPointer());
        item->setValue(value);
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Qt::ItemFlags QPropertyModel::flags ( const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
    Property *item = static_cast<Property*>(index.internalPointer());
    // only allow change of value attribute
    if (item->isRoot())
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;   
    else if (item->isReadOnly())
        return Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;    
    else
        return Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}


QVariant QPropertyModel::headerData ( int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role /*= Qt::DisplayRole*/ ) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole) 
    {
        switch (section) 
        {
             case 0:
                 return tr("Name");
             case 1:
                 return tr("Value");
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QModelIndex QPropertyModel::buddy ( const QModelIndex & index ) const 
{
    if (index.isValid() && index.column() == 0)
        return createIndex(index.row(), 1, index.internalPointer());
    return index;
}

void QPropertyModel::addItem(QObject *propertyObject)
{
    // first create property <-> class hierarchy
    QList<PropertyPair> propertyMap;
    QList<const QMetaObject*> classList;    
    const QMetaObject* metaObject = propertyObject->metaObject();   
    do
    {
        int count = metaObject->propertyCount();
        for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
        {
            QMetaProperty property = metaObject->property(i);
            if( property.isUser() ) // Hide Qt specific properties
            {               
                PropertyPair pair(metaObject, property);
                int index = propertyMap.indexOf(pair);
                if (index != -1)
                    propertyMap[index] = pair;
                else
                    propertyMap.push_back(pair);                
            }
        }       
        classList.push_front(metaObject);
    }
    while ((metaObject = metaObject->superClass())!=0);

    QList<const QMetaObject*> finalClassList;   
    // remove empty classes from hierarchy list
    foreach(const QMetaObject* obj, classList)
    {
        bool keep = false;
        foreach(PropertyPair pair, propertyMap)
        {
            if (pair.Object == obj)
            {
                keep = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (keep)
            finalClassList.push_back(obj);
    }

    // finally insert properties for classes containing them
    int i=rowCount();
    Property* propertyItem = 0;
    beginInsertRows( QModelIndex(), i, i + finalClassList.count() );
    foreach(const QMetaObject* metaObject, finalClassList)
    {
        // Set default name of the hierarchy property to the class name
        QString name = metaObject->className();
        // Check if there is a special name for the class
        int index = metaObject->indexOfClassInfo(qPrintable(name));
        if (index != -1)
            name = metaObject->classInfo(index).value();
        // Create Property Item for class node
        propertyItem = new Property(name, 0, m_rootItem);       
        foreach(PropertyPair pair, propertyMap)
        {
            // Check if the property is associated with the current class from the finalClassList
            if (pair.Object == metaObject)
            {
                QMetaProperty property(pair.Property);
                Property* p = 0;
                if (property.type() == QVariant::UserType && !m_userCallbacks.isEmpty())
                {
                    QList<QPropertyEditorWidget::UserTypeCB>::iterator iter = m_userCallbacks.begin();
                    while( p == 0 && iter != m_userCallbacks.end() )
                    {
                        p = (*iter)(property.name(), propertyObject, propertyItem);         
                        ++iter;
                    }
                }
                if( p == 0){
                    if(property.isEnumType()){
                        p = new EnumProperty(property.name(), propertyObject, propertyItem);
                    } else {
                        p = new Property(property.name(), propertyObject, propertyItem);
                    }
                }
                int index = metaObject->indexOfClassInfo(property.name());
                if (index != -1)        
                    p->setEditorHints(metaObject->classInfo(index).value());            
            }
        }
    }
    endInsertRows();
    if( propertyItem )  addDynamicProperties( propertyItem, propertyObject );
}

void QPropertyModel::updateItem ( QObject* propertyObject, const QModelIndex& parent /*= QModelIndex() */ ) 
{
    Property *parentItem = m_rootItem;
    if (parent.isValid())
        parentItem = static_cast<Property*>(parent.internalPointer());  
    if (parentItem->propertyObject() != propertyObject)     
        parentItem = parentItem->findPropertyObject(propertyObject);
    if (parentItem) // Indicate view that the data for the indices have changed 
    {
        QModelIndex itemIndex = createIndex(parentItem->row(), 0, static_cast<Property*>(parentItem));
        dataChanged(itemIndex, createIndex(parentItem->row(), 1, static_cast<Property*>(parentItem)));      
        QList<QByteArray> dynamicProperties = propertyObject->dynamicPropertyNames();
        QList<QObject*> childs = parentItem->parent()->children();
        int removed = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < childs.count(); ++i )
        {
            QObject* obj = childs[i];
            if( !obj->property("__Dynamic").toBool() || dynamicProperties.contains( obj->objectName().toLocal8Bit() ) ) 
                continue;
            beginRemoveRows(itemIndex.parent(), i - removed, i - removed);
            ++removed;
            delete obj;
            endRemoveRows();
        }
        addDynamicProperties(static_cast<Property*>(parentItem->parent()), propertyObject);
    }
}

void QPropertyModel::addDynamicProperties( Property* parent, QObject* propertyObject )
{
    // Get dynamic property names
    QList<QByteArray> dynamicProperties = propertyObject->dynamicPropertyNames();

    QList<QObject*> childs = parent->children();

    // Remove already existing properties from list 
    for(int i = 0; i < childs.count(); ++i )
    {       
        if( !childs[i]->property("__Dynamic").toBool() ) continue;

        int index = dynamicProperties.indexOf( childs[i]->objectName().toLocal8Bit() );
        if( index != -1)
        {
            dynamicProperties.removeAt(index);          
            continue;
        }
    }   

    // Remove invalid properites and those we don't want to add
    for(int i = 0; i < dynamicProperties.size(); ++i )
    {
        QString dynProp = dynamicProperties[i];
        // Skip properties starting with _ (because there may be dynamic properties from Qt with _q_ and we may
        // have user defined hidden properties starting with _ too
        if( dynProp.startsWith("_") || !propertyObject->property( qPrintable(dynProp) ).isValid() )
        {
            dynamicProperties.removeAt(i);
            --i;
        }       
    }

    if( dynamicProperties.empty() ) return;

    QModelIndex parentIndex = createIndex(parent->row(), 0, static_cast<Property*>(parent));
    int rows = rowCount(parentIndex);
    beginInsertRows(parentIndex, rows, rows + dynamicProperties.count() - 1 );
    // Add properties left in the list
    foreach(QByteArray dynProp, dynamicProperties )
    {
        QVariant v = propertyObject->property(dynProp);
        Property* p = 0;
        if( v.type() == QVariant::UserType && !m_userCallbacks.isEmpty() )
        {
            QList<QPropertyEditorWidget::UserTypeCB>::iterator iter = m_userCallbacks.begin();
            while( p == 0 && iter != m_userCallbacks.end() )
            {
                p = (*iter)(dynProp, propertyObject, parent);           
                ++iter;
            }
        }
        if( p == 0 ) p = new Property(dynProp, propertyObject, parent);
        p->setProperty("__Dynamic", true);
    }
    endInsertRows();
}

void QPropertyModel::clear()
{
    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), 0, rowCount());
    delete m_rootItem;
    m_rootItem = new Property("Root",0, this);   
    endRemoveRows();
}

void QPropertyModel::registerCustomPropertyCB(QPropertyEditorWidget::UserTypeCB callback)
{
    if ( !m_userCallbacks.contains(callback) )
        m_userCallbacks.push_back(callback);
}

void QPropertyModel::unregisterCustomPropertyCB(QPropertyEditorWidget::UserTypeCB callback)
{
    int index = m_userCallbacks.indexOf(callback);
    if( index != -1 )
        m_userCallbacks.removeAt(index);
}
```

Comment: What you mean is that you would like to have an object whose *type* is a property, and then it'd morph itself based on that property. Of course an object doesn't need to morph. It can simply delete itself and replace itself with something else :)

Comment: I also don't understand what for do you have a `Property` type when you essentially duplicate what `QStandardItem` does, except that you add direct C++ interfaces that seem not to have any use. And of course your `Property` interface pretends to be a model, but is not.

Comment: @KubaOber added property model.

Answer (score 0):

`QObject` has a dynamic property system, so you do not need to manually declare any properties at all. It'd be easy to map such objects to an item view. But it seems like the use of a `QObject` is overkill.

It seems like you'd be completely covered by using a `QStandardItemModel` and its items, arranged in a tree. An item could be either a plant, or a plant's property.

Comment: Much of the project is written with this pattern, can you think of a solution keeping this qProperty pattern?  If not do you have links to examples of this behavior being created in another way.

Comment: @richgreen The thing is: you do not demonstrate any need for the use of a `QObject` and for manually declaring the properties as things that have names known to the C++ compiler. All the names are usable to the views etc. You'd have to make a case for the use of `Q_PROPERTY` macros and of having properties that the compiler knows about. I don't see it yet.